# How to have CASE statement look at previous records in the statement

Tags: t-sql, case

I have the following code generating a case statement in which I would like all future time periods to return 'Graduated' if the student graduated in a previous time period. Here is the current code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Z1.StudentID,
Z1.AcadLevel,
Z1.StudentAcadLevel,
Z1.StudentCohortStartDate,
Z1.PeriodID,
Z2.CourseTimePeriod,
Z3.DegreeTimePeriod,
CASE
  WHEN Z1.PeriodID = '0' THEN 'CohortStart'
  WHEN Z3.DegreeTimePeriod <= Z1.PeriodID THEN 'Graduated'
  WHEN Z1.PeriodID = Z2.CourseTimePeriod THEN 'Retained'
  WHEN Z2.CourseTimePeriod IS NULL THEN 'Churned'
  ELSE 'Fix Me'
END AS TimePeriodStatus
FROM Z_Retention_StudentTimePeriodStatus Z1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Z_Retention_StudentCourseRegistrations Z2 ON Z2.StudentID = Z1.StudentID AND Z2.STC_ACAD_LEVEL = Z1.AcadLevel AND Z2.CourseTimePeriod = Z1.PeriodID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Z_Retention_StudentDegree Z3 ON Z3.StudentID = Z1.StudentID AND Z3.DegreeAcadLevel = Z1.AcadLevel AND Z3.DegreeTimePeriod = Z1.PeriodID
ORDER BY Z1.StudentID, Z1.PeriodID, Z2.CourseTimePeriod
```

In the attached image, I'm hoping to add a line to the case statement that would make the highlighted rows return 'Graduated' rather than 'Churned'.

[image]

Comment: Adding DDL, sample data and a hint as to how you determine the status would help us help you. Aside: It is a `case` _expression_, not statement.

Comment: Need to also be able to see the missing columns - StudentId, AcadLevel, StudentAcadLevel, StudentCohortStartDate. Based on info provided we're left to assume a lot.